# how to display a csv file in line protocol format?

Tags: python, csv, influxdb

How do I display a CSV file in line protocol format, like `influxdb` uses?

```
measurement[,tag_key1=tag_value1...]
field_key=field_value[,field_key2=field_value2] [timestamp]
```

suppose my csv file is as follows:

```
Date          Time            place       status      action
2 sep 2016   12:05:50:274     abc          on         batery on
16 sep 2016  12:05:51:275     mbc          on         batery on
22 sep 2016  12:05:52:276     kabc          on        batery on
```

I am able to read the entire csv file line by line by using the code:

```
**with open('test.csv') as fp:
      for line in fp:
         print line**
```

and i'm getting the o/p as :

```
['Date','Time','place','status','action']
['2 sep 2016','12:05:50:274','abc','on','batery on']['16 sep 2016','12:05:51:275','mbc',     'on','batery on']['22 sep 2016','12:05:52:276','kabc','on','batery on']
```

Whereas I want the out put to in lineprotocol format/syntax such as:

```
Date=2 sep 2016,place=abc,'status=on,action=battery on,Time=12:05:50:274
```

And also I want the code to be able to convert , `Time=12:05:50:274` into epoch time so that it can be used as timestamp in line protocol for `influx db`.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use the "Date" attribute of a row as well, in order to convert to epoch time. Here's one way you could do it:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import csv
from datetime import datetime as dt

with open('test.csv') as infile:
    headers = next(csv.reader(infile))

with open('test.csv') as infile:
    for row in csv.DictReader(infile):
        row['Time'] = dt.strptime(row['Date'] + " " + row['Time'].rsplit(":",1)[0], "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
        print(','.join(["%s=%s" %(header, row[header]) for header in headers])
```

Comment: @inspectorG4dget How this csv file can be saved in localsystem ?

Comment: @suryarahul: it is not saved in the filesystem; it only displays to the console. If you want to save to the filesystem, you could use IO redirection or edit the `print` to include an open file object